# ip link bridge error on Ubuntu in Parallels Apple Silicon

Tags: ubuntu, apple-silicon, parallels, netlink

When trying to add bridge link I'm getting following error:

```
sudo ip link add br0 type bridge
RTNETLINK answers: No such device
```

It is Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS running on M1 Pro Mac in Parallels Win 11 Pro 22H2 64-bin ARM in WSL 1 mode.

```
wsluser@USER:~$ uname --a
Linux USER 4.4.0-22621-Microsoft #2506-Microsoft Fri Jan 01 08:00:00 PST 2016 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

How to make it work in this config?

Comment: Stack Overflow is specific to programming questions, you might have more luck over at [su].